# Logical combinations the Java-way: Don't test second case if first is already false

Tags: r, logic

I know that in Java it is often quite handy to do things like that

```
if(a!=0 && b/a>1){
  ...;
}
```

Java stops when the first part is already false. R does not do that, producing errors sometimes. So: Is there a possibility to make this code shorter:

```
if(exists("user_set_variable")){
   if(user_set_variable < 3){
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?'&&'` you can find

```
& and && indicate logical AND and | and || indicate logical OR.
The shorter form performs elementwise comparisons in much the same
way as arithmetic operators. The longer form evaluates left to right 
examining only the first element of each vector. Evaluation proceeds
only until the result is determined. The longer form is appropriate
for programming control-flow and typically preferred in if clauses.
```

So probably you're looking for `&` instead of `&&`. See these examples where two conditions are evaluated:

```
# Case 1
a<- 2
b <- 4

 if(a!=0 &  b/a>1){
   print('Hello World')
 } else{
   print("one or both conditions not met")
 }
[1] "Hello World"

# Case 2
a<- 2
 b <- 1

 if(a!=0 & b/a>1){
   print('Hello World')
 } else{
  print("one or both conditions not met")
 }
[1] "one or both conditions not met"


 # Case 3
 a<- 0
 b <- 1

 if(a!=0 &  b/a>1){
   print('Hello World')
 } else{
  print("one or both conditions not met")
 }
[1] "one or both conditions not met"
```

Comment: This example would be more useful (I think) if you make the second condition throw an error, and show which of your cases do not throw the error, thus clearly showing the short-circuit.

Comment: Thank you @CarlWitthoft, very helpful comment. I already edited my answer.

Comment: Surely its the `&&` version that is needed. `b/a` doesn't produce an error in R for `a = 0`, it produces `Inf` which can be compared to finite values without issue.

Comment: Well I'm not sure. I think when the OP reads `?'&&'` will get clarified

Comment: Try running the test cases but after `rm(b)` so there is no such object.  that will throw an error whenever there's a test involving `b`

Answer (score 5):

R also short-circuits the `&&` and `||` operators when the second argument doesn't need to be evaluated. For example (here `x` does not exist)

```
> if (exists('x') && x < 3) { print('do this') } else { print ('do that') }
[1] "do that"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use the short-circuit statements if those are clear enough as they are or you could just wrap your multiple if statement lines into a function.  Here's some pseudo-code for a visual.

> if(exists("user_set_variable")){    if(user_set_variable < 3){
>         ...    } }

Could then be:

```
var<- "user_set_variable" 'let var be your variable for this
if(exists(var) && var < 3)
{ 'do stuff }
```

or do this:

```
'function definition
Function boolean IsValidVar(variable)
{
     if(exists(var))
     {
         if(var < 3)
         { return true; }}
     return false;
}
```

then your program looks like so:

```
var<- "user_set_variable" 'let var be your variable for this
if(IsValidVar(var))
{ 'do stuff }
```

It's really just your call what seems simple.